# How to update a single attribute?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, loopbackjs

when I upload a new asset on my application, I need to update in the database only the `uri` attribute.

```
function assegnaUri(hash_referto, proprietario, public_key, data_esame, tipo_esame, uri) {

   fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/REFERTOs', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: { 
   Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
     body: JSON.stringify({
   "hash_referto":hash_referto,
   "proprietario":proprietario,
   "public_key":public_key,
   "data_esame": data_esame, 
   "tipo_esame":tipo_esame,
   "uri":uri
     }),
 });
 }
```

hash_referto is the id, I just need to get the right tuple with the `id` and upload `uri` from `null` to a value stored in `referto`

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear what you want to get done, it think you want a UPDATE request ?

```
function assegnaUri(hash_referto, uri) {

   fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/REFERTOs', {
   method: 'PUT',
   headers: { 
   Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
     body: JSON.stringify({
   hash_referto:hash_referto,
   uri:uri
     }),
 });
 }
```

I always use PUT request to update something, we can dive into the details if you want to, now you need to handle this request in your back-End